# require() must have a single string literal argument React Native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I've  component in my application which works fine if it is assigned direct string value("someImage.png"), but if I try to assign it by storing image name in a local variable it gives this exception "require() must have a single string literal argument"
This line works fine

```
<ImageBackground source={require("./Resources/bg/imageone.png")} resizeMode='cover' style={customStyles.backdrop}>
```

Issue occurs in this case

```
let imageName = "./Resources/bg/imageone.png";          
<ImageBackground id="123" source={require(imageName)} resizeMode='cover' style={customStyles.backdrop}>
```

I also found same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042892/react-native-require-must-have-a-sing-string-literal-argument), but no one has answered that yet. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This example of dynamic images can also show how to correctly assign a variable with the image source value. The recommendation is to assign the whole `require` in a variable, instead of just its value.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Hope it helps

Comment: You could also look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16216) on Github.

Comment: @soutot it works, but I think react-native should really add support to accept variable in require(), what if document path is vary large, this could easily introduce typing mistakes and change would cost more time.

Comment: @SergeK. my react-native version is 0.51.0  node : v8.9.3 & npm: 4.6.1

Comment: And what if I have different icons?

Comment: What if the image name is totally dynamic and being passed in props? How will we render that?

Comment: @Picci if you have different icons, you should store the whole require in a variable, as the example above shows under ```// GOOD``` comment line.
@MuhammadHannan that's not possible to render images that way. Since your bundle must know exactly all images it should load before the app runs, all images paths should be static. I haven't check if any new release fixed it, but as far as I know, that's how it works

Comment: Downvote for copy/paste. Doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Green, Yes, the code provided does answer the question, just pay attention to the code under ```// GOOD``` comment. As I mentioned in the answer text, It represents the correct way to assign an image variable. Also, the official docs are the best resources for answering questions. No shame on copying/pasting from it.

Answer (score 8):

If you have indexes in the data then my approach to the issue is:

```
const image1 = require('../assets/images/image1.png');
const image2 = require('../assets/images/image2.png');
const image3 = require('../assets/images/image3.png');

const images = [image1, image2, image3];

...

<Image source={images[index]} />
```

Comment: I wanted a way which doesn't involve writing `require('pathToImage')` multiple times

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a helper component that I use quite often:

```
import your-image-name from '<path-to-image>';

const images = {
  your-image-name,
};

getImage = name => images[name];

export default getImage;
```

Then, inside the component you need the image:

```
import getImage from '<path>';

<Image source={getImage('your-image-name')} />
```

Importing the image within the helper function removes the need to use `require()`.

From there, you can import all your images into the `getImage` component.

If you would like to take it a step further, you can create a new `Image` component that takes in `name` as a prop. For example:

```
import { Image as RNImage } from 'react-native';

import getImage from '<path>';

const Image = ({ name, source, ...props }) => (
  <RNImage
    source={name ? getImage(name) : source}
    {...props}
  />
);

export default Image;
```

***Importing `Image` using `as RNImage` is used to avoid a duplicate declaration error.***

Then

```
import Image from '<path>';

<Image name="your-image-name" />
```

This also leaves you the ability to use `source` as a prop within the new `Image` component in case you ever need to use a URI instead of a relative path. Along with any other props you need to pass.

From there, you will have access to the `getImage` component without having to import it across multiple components within your app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

//-Convert image path to Array list

```
   indexImag = [
    require("./img/KPN48-01.jpg"),
    require("./img/KPN48-02.jpg"),
    require("./img/KPN48-03.jpg")
  ];
```

//-data Feed--

```
dataFeed = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Koisuru Fietune Cookie คุกกี้เสี่ยงทาย",
      subTitle: "128,136,082 views",
      imgId: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "BNK48 - คุกกี้เสี่ยงทาย Koisuru Fortune Cookie Cover",
      subTitle: "328,006,000 views",
      imgId: 1
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "คลาสเด็ก - คุกกี้เสี่ยงทาย - BNK48 - Koisuru Fortune Cookie",
      subTitle: "334,111,234 views",
      imgId: 2
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title:
        "เชิญชวนมาร่วมถ่าย MV BNK48 Koisuru Foutune Cookie คุกกี้เสี่ยงทาย",
      subTitle: "100,000,055 views",
      imgId: 0
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title:
        "หนุ่มๆ ฟินทั้งประเทศ! ฟังเพลงฮิต คุกกี้เสี่ยงทาย อีก 3 เวอร์ชั่นจากวงพี่สาว ",
      subTitle: "400,143,634 views",
      imgId: 1
    }
  ];
```

//-render--

```
 <View>
    <View>
      <Image

        source={require("./img/LogoPP.png")}
      />
      <View>
        <Text>{_item.textTitle} </Text>
        <Text>{_item.subTitle} </Text>
      </View>
    </View>

    <Image

      source={this.indexImag[_item.imgId]}
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Perfect Solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution there if you have more than 2 choices is to pass the result of the require as a parameter instead of do a require(param) inside the method.

```
render() {
   return (
    <ScrollView>
        {this.renderMenuItem("CATALOGO", require('../../img/hp_catalogo.jpg'), this.goToCatalogo)}
        {this.renderMenuItem("NOVITÀ PRODOTTI", require('../../img/hp_novita.jpg'), this.goToNovita)}
    </ScrollView>);
}

renderMenuItem(name, imagePath, func ){
     return (
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={func} style={styles.box}>
         <ImageBackground
           source={imagePath}
           style={styles.image}>
           <Text>{name}</Text>
         </ImageBackground>
         <TouchableOpacity>);
         }
```

Comment: I've multiple choices & it gives me headache `require(whole path to image)` multiple times, I just posted to know if there is a better alternate than writing require() equal to number of choices.