# how to put icon inside my 'box' in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have build a 'box' that contain my style to the components, I have manage to put there only text but no success with icon/image plz help

I have build a 'box' that contain my style to the components, I have manage to put there only text but no success with icon/image plz help

I have build a 'box' that contain my style to the components, I have manage to put there only text but no success with icon/image plz help

```
App:

.....import Box from './src/box';
......

<View style={{height: 100,flexDirection:'row',flex:1}}>
          <Box someText={'sushi'}
          //, background source={require('./assets/sushi.png')}
          //,TouchableHighlight onPress={this.message_function}
          />
</View>

box:

import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text,View ,Image} from "react-native";
import React from 'react' ;

export default class Box extends React.Component {

   render() {
       return (
       <View style={styles.box}>

   <Text style={styles.paragraph}> {this.props.someText}</Text>
       </View>
       );
   }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    box: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 100,
        //backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        margin: 8,



    },
    paragraph: {


    //margin: 24,
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlignVertical:10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'bottom',
    //top:0, left: 0, right: 0,
    color: '#000',
     width: '100%',
      height: '70%',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap an `<Image>` or Icon component within your box `<View>`

So it will end up something like this:

```
<View style={styles.box}>
  <Image source={require('your-image-path')} />
</View>
```

Image component docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

There are several libs to handle Icon component:

React Native Elements: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/icon.html

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'

<Icon name='rowing' />
```

React Native Vector Icons: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

<Icon name="user" />
```

React Native Icons: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons

```
import Icon from 'react-native-icons';
<Icon
  name='ion|beer'
  size={40}
  color='#887700'
/>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can you give an example to put a universal image like I did with the text? (this.props.someText)

Comment: I think this answer can help you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887697/require-must-have-a-single-string-literal-argument-react-native/47887881#47887881