# Dynamic render <Image> component by passing props

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, components

Is there a way to do something like that in React Native :

```
<Image source={require("../../../assets/imgList/" + this.props.imgName + ".png")} />
```

I got this error:

> 'require' expect exactly 1 string literal argument.

Thank you.

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887697/require-must-have-a-single-string-literal-argument-react-native

Comment: No, this is not exactly solving my problem. I already found the documentation, but I do not want to write every single path to my images, and this is not a simple boolean but a big big list.

Comment: Then you should offload this path generation to a separate method and invoke that to retrieve the final string.

Comment: I tried to do so but I got the same error. I mean call a method that will generate my string (let's say iconPath) then you call require(iconPath).

Comment: `require()` resolves your path at compile time before your app even runs. So you can't pass it a string that can only be resolved at run time. It must be a string literal.

Comment: So this is completely impossible @trixn ? Thank you for the explications.

Comment: @Gouigoui I'm not exactly sure. Webpack is able to do that. I believe that react-native uses the metro bundler which can only resolve that at compile time. The problem is that this kind of statement needs to be transformed into code that actually fetches the missing file when your application runs because only then the path is known. I think this is, what webpack does. So it is not trivial. The transpiler must replace that call to `require` with some kind of loader that actually knows how to get that image. If the path would be known before, the image can simply be bundled into the app.

Comment: @Gouigoui Also see [Network Images](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-images) in the react-native docs for alternatives.